# What property of a Templatefield will make an asp button visible?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code on my aspx page that has an onclick event to produce a popup control but the button is invisible. What can I use in place of ItemTemplate as a property of Templatefield to make the button visible?

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Performance Status (adults):">
        <ItemTemplate>                
            <asp:button skinID="tabbutton" CssClass="Clickable" id="btnWhoStatus" runat="server" Text="?" BorderStyle="None" TabIndex="-1" />
            <cc1:PopupControlExtender
                ID="PopupControlExtender2" runat="server" Position="Top" 
                TargetControlID="btnWhoStatus" PopupControlID="pnlWhoStatus" 
                DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="">
            </cc1:PopupControlExtender>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlWhoStatus" BackColor="#FFFFFF" style="width:640px; display:none "  >
                <controls:WhoStatusPopup id="WhoStatusPopup" runat="server"  />
            </asp:Panel>                
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>                
            <asp:Label skinid="tablabelblack" id="lblPerformanceStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PerformanceStatus") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: why not just use `Visible` property of button itself ?

Comment: @Sachin that doesn't seem to work?